# Merging a property with different types using deepmerge.js

Tags: javascript, merge

I'm trying to create a flexible merging structure for arrays using [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge), similar to mongodb, where I can pass an object that tells what type of merge the array should make.

The idea is to have something like this:

```js
let a = {
   foo: [1, 2, 3]
};

let b = {
   foo: [4, 5, 6]
}

deepmerge(a, b, someOptions);
// would result { foo: [4, 5, 6] }

let c = {
   foo: { $push: [4, 5, 6] }
}

deepmerge(a, b, someOptions);
// would result { foo: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }
```

Similarly I could also use `$unshift` for example.

The thing is I couldn't figure out what are the `someOptions` I can pass to make this happen.

`arrayMerge` doen't work because it is never called for the second `foo`, since it's not an array. `customMerge` doesn't work ether because I don't have the type information, just the name of the field (which can be anything).

Is there any combination of options that I can use to make this? I'm not tied to deepmerge, so I'm open to other solutions too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't find the answer for a week so I had to create a lib myself hahahah

I called it deepmerge-json (yes, I know, I'm "the best" with names) and it's [available on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge-json). It's just a simple deep merge with some array merging functions. Any suggestions will be welcome.